# JS Set.has() returning false boolean value when item is present

Tags: javascript, set

I have written a recursive function that has a base case, but it is not terminating because of an if statement that reads the values in a set.  `timestamps.has()` always returns `false` even when it "should be" returning `true`.

I am unable to track down the bug, and am wondering if I am doing something wrong that is simple, such as the scoping of the `timestamps` variable, I have already checked the values in the set and the values that are compared and they are in fact equivalent, so I am not sure what is wrong.

```
var timestamps;

trackFraud = async () => {

  account = document.getElementById("account").value;

  timestamps = new Set();

  await fraudClimb(account, 0);

  async function fraudClimb(account, theseTimestamps) {

    var [frauds, theseTimestamps] = await findFraudByFromAccount.call(this, account, theseTimestamps);

    if (frauds.length == 0) return;

    for (var i = 0; i < frauds.length; i++) {
      await fraudClimb(frauds[i], theseTimestamps[i]);
    }
  }
}

findFraudByFromAccount = async (account, timestamp) => {
  events = await window.KYCinstance.getPastEvents('ReportedFraudB', { filter: {fromAccount: web3.utils.fromAscii(account)}, fromBlock: 0 });
  var frauds = [];
  var theseTimestamps = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    let values = events[i].returnValues;

    if (timestamps.has(values.times)) continue;  //THIS LINE IS NEVER FAILING
    else {
      timestamps.add(values.time);
      theseTimestamps.push(values.time);
      frauds.push(web3.utils.toAscii(values.fromAccount)); 
    }
  }
  return [frauds, theseTimestamps];
}
```

Comment: What is `values.times` and `values.time` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a mismatch here:

```
                                extra 's'
                               /
if (timestamps.has(values.times)) continue;
else {
  timestamps.add(values.time);
                            \
                             no 's' here
  ...
```

Depending on your `values` object structure, this might be crucial. Your `has` check will return `false` if these properties are not equal or if one of them does not exist.